# How to use loops to scrape data from API

Tags: python, api, loops, for-loop, web-scraping

I am scraping data from API and it has parameters: "limit" and "newest", where "limit" sets how many items I am going to get (100 max) and "newest" is like the starting point.

I managed to look up some answers but I am stuck with what I have so far:

```
import requests

def main(search_term):
    url = "https://shopee.sg/api/v4/search/search_items?by=relevancy&categoryids=100630&keyword=" + search_term
    
    params = {
        "by": "relevancy",
        "keyword": search_term,
        "limit": "100",  # maximum is 100 per page
        "newest": "0",
        "order": "desc",
        "page_type": "search",
        "scenario": "PAGE_GLOBAL_SEARCH",
        "version": "2"
    }
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    
    j = 1
    # print(f"Total Count: {r.json()['total_count']}") # can be used as a logic for loop
    for i in r.json()['items']:

        # NAME
        name = (i['item_basic']['name'])
        print("Name: " + (i['item_basic']['name']))
        
        # BRAND
        if (i['item_basic']['brand']) is None:
            print("")
        else:
            brand = i['item_basic']['brand']
            print("Brand: " + i['item_basic']['brand'])

# SCRAPES FIRST 100 ITEMS (0 to 100th item)
main("make-up")
```

This code would scrape 1st item to 100th item and if I changed the "newsest" from 0 to 100, I think it should scrape 101st item to 200th item.

Problem is I'm not sure what to do if I wanted to scrape a certain number of itmes like 60 items or 140 items or 270 items?

I think I need to do something like this:

```
def main(search_term):
    url = "https://shopee.sg/api/v4/search/search_items?by=relevancy&categoryids=100630&keyword=" + search_term
    
    # LOOP HERE TO SCRAPE 250 items 
    for num in range(0, 250) # 0 to 250 items

        params = {
            "by": "relevancy",
            "keyword": search_term,
            "limit": 100, # something here using num
            "newest": 0, # something here using num
            "order": "desc",
            "page_type": "search",
            "scenario": "PAGE_GLOBAL_SEARCH",
            "version": "2"
        }
        r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    
        j = 1
        # print(f"Total Count: {r.json()['total_count']}") # can be used as a logic for loop
        for i in r.json()['items']:

            basic = i['item_basic']

            # NAME
            name = (basic['name'])
            print("Name: " + (basic['name']))
        
            # BRAND
            if (basic['brand']) is None:
                print("")
            else:
                brand = basic['brand']
                print("Brand: " + basic['brand'])

            # URL
            base_template = "https://shopee.sg/"
            name = basic['name']
            url_name = name.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(" ", "-").replace("/", "-")
            shop_id = basic['shopid']
            item_id = basic['itemid']
            url = base_template + url_name + "-i." + str(shop_id) + "." + str(item_id)
            print(url)


main("make-up")
```

Something like this to scrape 250 items by calling the main function once but I just can't seem to figure it out

Comment: in question (not in comment) you should add link to API documentation.

Comment: you could add all parameters in `params`, and use only `url = "https://shopee.sg/api/v4/search/search_items"` - and `requests` will add all parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show link to API documentations which could explain params so I only guess.

Use `for`-loop with step `100` and change `newest` in params.

```
for offset in range(0, 250, 100) # 0 to 250 items

    params = {
        "newest": offset,
        # ... other params ...
    }
```

---

**EDIT:**

Working code with other changes

```
import requests

# --- functions ---

def main(search_term, items_number=250):
    
    url = "https://shopee.sg/api/v4/search/search_items"

    params = {
        "by": "relevancy",
        "categoryids": 100630,
        "keyword": search_term,
        "limit": 100,  # default value at start
        "newest": 0,   # default value at start
        "order": "desc",
        "page_type": "search",
        "scenario": "PAGE_GLOBAL_SEARCH",
        "version": "2"
    }

    for offset in range(0, items_number, 100):

        print('\n--- offset:', offset, '---\n')

        params["newest"] = offset   # other parameters are the same
        
        limit = items_number - offset
        if limit < 100:
            params["limit"] = limit
        
        r = requests.get(url, params=params)
        data = r.json()    

        print('>> items number in data:', len(data['items']), '\n')
        
        for number, item in enumerate(data['items']):

            print('number:', offset+number+1)
            
            basic = item['item_basic']
            
            #print('keys:', basic.keys())
            #for key, value in basic.items():
            #    print(f"{key}: {value}")
            
            # NAME
            name = basic['name']
            #name = basic.get('name', '- unknown -')  # safer if `name` may not exists in `data`
            print("Name:", name)
        
            # BRAND
            #brand = basic['brand']
            brand = basic.get('brand')  # safer if `brand` may not exists in `data`
            if brand is None:
                print()
            else:
                print("Brand:", brand)

            print('---')
            
# --- main ---

main("make-up")
#main("make-up", 60)
#main("make-up", 270)
```

Comment: I set the "newest" and "limit" to "num" (not "number") and got an "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" when I tried it?

Comment: don't change limit - it has to be alwayst 100. And error means server didn't send JSON data and you should check `print( r.text )` to see what you get. Maybe it sends HTML with warning or some explanation.

Comment: oh wow this looks amazing, one question though, I tried changing the "items_number" in the main function argument and it seems to show 300 results if I picked any number between 200. and 300 and 200 results for any number between 100-200?

Comment: it would need to reduce `limit` in last request - but it need more code so I skiped this part. Eventually in new code in answer you can use `offset+number` to exit function when `offset+number > items_number`

Comment: I changed code and now it calculate `limit`

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand your question clearly.

If you want to control elements to process inside your loop, you may set start element and number of elements to process

```py
def main(search_term, skip=0, limit=100):

    ...

    for i in r.json()['items'][skip:(limit+skip)]:

        ....
```

```
# process first 100 elements
main(some_variable, 0, 100)

# process second 100 elements
main(some_variable, 100, 100)

# process 50 elements starting from 11th element
main(some_variable, 10, 50)
```

if you want to grab exact number of elements you need to set it in params:

```py
def main(search_term, skip="0", limit="100"):

    ...
    
    params = {
        "by": "relevancy",
        "keyword": search_term,
        "limit": limit,  # maximum is 100 per page
        "newest": skip,
        "order": "desc",
        "page_type": "search",
        "scenario": "PAGE_GLOBAL_SEARCH",
        "version": "2"
    }
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)

    ...
```

Comment: I don't want to individually call the main function to scrape data

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. `main` function must decide automatically how many elements you want to scrape?

Comment: not automatically but given which ever number of items/elements I want to scrape. I kinda updated my answer to what I want

Comment: like, if I want to scrape 150 items, I want to put 150 somewhere in the code so I can get all 150 items by calling the function once

Comment: I'd have to call the main function three times to scrape 250 items in your first solution and pretty much the same for your second solution